# How to properly write unit tests for router modules in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, sinon-chai

I'm new to nodeJS and testing and I'd like to know how I can test my application routes properly. I've read some articles that uses **supertest** and **chai-http** to call the POST method but I believe this way would be more of an integration testing instead of unit testing my app.

I've read about Sinon but I'm having a hard time applying it on my code like I don't know what to stub, how I can manipulate the data from the request body so I can cover different branches of my conditional statements. I'm monitoring my code coverage with **nyc** so I'm also aiming to increase my unit test coverage.

I would appreciate it a lot if someone can guide me on this. Thanks in advance!

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.listen(8080, function () {
    logger.info('App is now running on port 8080');
});

app.use('/', require('./routes/generateURL.js'));

module.exports = app;
```

**generateURL.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/generate-url', (req, res) => {
    let result = {
        status: false
    };
    const acctId = req.body.accountId;
    const baseURL = 'http://somecompany.com/billing/';
    const dateToday = new Date();

    try {
        if (accountId) {
            result.status = true;
            result.bill = baseURL + acctId + '/' + dateToday;
        } else {
            throw 'Missing accountId';
        }
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    return res.send(result);
});

module.exports = router;
```